# FosBundle Route Not Found

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

Currently following the tutorial of [how to create Rest API](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/rest-api-in-symfony-3-1/) on Symfony 3.x.

My problem is im stuck with `getAction()` method using this code.

```
namespace SwipeBundle\Controller\Backend\API;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

class UserController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/api/user")
     */
    public function getAction() {
        $restresult = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('SwipeBundle:User')
            ->findAll();

        if ($restresult) {
            return new View("there are no users exist", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return $restresult;
    }
}
```

checking the error on the logs:

> Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /api/user"" at
>   /home/swipecom/contactless/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 4595
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code:
>   0): No route found for \"GET /api/user\" at
>   /home/swipecom/contactless/var/cache/prod/classes.php:4595,
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code:
>   0):  at
>   /home/swipecom/contactless/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:750)"}
>   []

I checked and configured the `FOSRest configuration and Nelmio` but still not working.

Here it is:

```
# Nelmio CORS Configuration
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
        max_age: 3600
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false

# FOSRest Configuration
fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['text/html'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/api/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
            xml: true
            yml: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the path attribute as example:

```
 * @Rest\Get(path="/api/user")
```

instead of

```
 * @Rest\Get("/api/user")
```

You can debug with the console command:

**To show all available route:**

> console debug:router

**To see who match your route:**

> console router:match /api/user

NB:

If the problem persist check with the command

> console debug:router --show-controllers

and looking for your controller and see what happen. As example, if your controller is not listed check the routing configuration as described in the doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html#single-restful-controller-routes).

Hope this help

Comment: I just added a path attribute to my route. path="/api/user" still not working, I've checked the router also using the router:match and error say None of the routes match the path

Comment: @phpmeter See my update: try with `console debug:router --show-controllers` and search for your controller

Comment: Can't find the userController that I created. :( How do I solve this issue?

Comment: @phpmeter check the official doc (probably the tutorial miss some detail) as example if you add the configuration of the bundle in the `routing.yml` files as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html#single-restful-controller-routes)

Comment: Update: I can now see the controllers, but I haven't get the route

Comment: @phpmeter which path is assigned to the controller?